# Access to Trading Pairs (Buy/Sell) using Coinbase OAuth for third-party applications

Tags: ethereum, algorithmic-trading, coinbase-api, cryptoapi

I am working on a project that would enable users to Sign In with Coibnase and place market orders for different coin pairs.

Eg: - Buy DOT, Buy LINK, etc

Does the Wallet API endpoints specifically - Buy resource, help in doing that?

I have these questions - as it mentions and I quote, "Buy resource represents a purchase of bitcoin, bitcoin cash, litecoin or Ethereum using a payment method (either a bank or a fiat account)."

I want to trade on behalf of users once they have authorized through OAuth (and, of course, the key contains appropriate permission).

To be clear again, I want to buy different pairs (or swap them for Ethereum/BTC). Can we do this?

If not what is the alternative to do the same using OAuth (on behalf of users)???